# vb.net cannot find file after file has been deleted and resaved by remote pc

Tags: vb.net, file

I'm using a web page to create a file on a web server to control an Arduino device. The file gets created without issue. The problem exists when the VB app that controls the Arduino device reads the file and then deletes the file. After VB deletes the file the web app recreates the same file with new data. The VB app fails to see the new file. It still thinks the file has been deleted.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub TimerCheck4CameraFile_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerCheck4CameraFile.Tick
    Try
        ' Check if file exists if it doesn't leave this method.
        Dim DirectoryList As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\inetpub\wwwroot")
        Dim ArrayOfFilesFileInfo As IO.FileInfo() = DirectoryList.GetFiles("ServoDirection2Move.txt")
        Dim Fi As IO.FileInfo

        For Each Fi In ArrayOfFilesFileInfo
            If String.Compare("ServoDirection2Move.txt", Fi.Name) <> 0 Then 
                TextBox1.Text += vbCrLf + "Did NOT Find File."
                Exit Sub ' We DID NOT find the file so get out!
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        LabelStatus.Text = "Catch ex 1: " + ex.Message
    End Try

    ' Read in the file.
    Dim FileRead As String
    Try
        ' **POSSIBLE ISSUE HERE**.
        FileRead = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ServoDirection2Move.txt")
        ' Need better way to read txt file. It fails after file is deleted and can not read second file.

        TextBox1.Text += vbCrLf + "Moving Value: " + FileRead
    Catch ex As Exception
        LabelStatus.Text = "Catch ex: " + ex.Message
    End Try

    ' Check if it was UP.
    If String.Compare("UP", FileRead) = 0 Then
        ' Delete the file to prepare for a new one.
        System.IO.File.Delete("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ServoDirection2Move.txt")
        ' Move servo to proper location.
        Call PanningUp.PerformClick()
        LabelStatus.Text = "Done Moving: UP"  ' Update Status Bar.
        TimerCheck4CameraFile.Enabled = True ' Turn timer back on.
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: do you mixed 2 subs together or is this the full code of your timer? What is the interval of your timer?

Comment: Hi Marco, timer is set to 500. The task is short to complete. I also stripped out a lot of code to get to the point rasier. I also disable the timer when I’m inside the tick. Then re-enable it after. That part works due to feedback on screen. The code that reads the contents of the file is all in 1 sub. Thanks for looking into this its been 2 days now and the code cannot read the file on the second try. Rich

Comment: Al working, was only a Timer.Enable issue. Was turning it off but was not allowing itself to be turned on again.